# operate as https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux,but when Run Build Task ,show error

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Starting build...
Build finished with error:

/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld:/home/chenxin/Documents/projects/helloworld/.vscode/tasks.json: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld:/home/chenxin/Documents/projects/helloworld/.vscode/tasks.json:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to compile a JSON file other than the cpp file you are using. You should first switch to the tab of the cpp code and then run the task or run the build task